# Printing Infopath form 2010(.xml) in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: infopath

My question is related to printing an Infopath 2010 form in Sharepoint 2010.I designed an Infopath 2010 form in Infopath Designer 2010 and published it to a form library in Sharepoint 2010.The end user fill the form and store

Comment: Your question is missing the end part. What is your question? Printing Infopath is available OOTB via the Forms Services.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options:

1. Use Forms Services, which has a nice print button, but your form will need to be browser enabled / compatible and you need to run the (paid for) MOSS 2007 / SharePoint Server 2010.
2. Just click the form, open it in InfoPath filler and print from there. This will give you the best result.
3. Use a third party tool to [convert it to PDF](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-for-SharePoint/summary.aspx), either in real time or [from a workflow](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/batch-print-infopath-forms-using-pdf.html). And use that for printing.

Please note that the links for the third party tool point to the Muhimbi PDF Converter for SharePoint. A product I have been involved in so the usual disclaimers apply.